# CombineReducers() defines, but state is always undefined

Tags: redux

I did use *combineReducers()* and the *initialState* is defined in each reducer separately.

The issue is: 
-> the state seem to be always undefined, even within the reducer, I tried to `console.log({...state})` and I get an empty object.
When I replace *state* with *initialState* in each return{} then I get the initialState data.

I tried in the *clientsReducer* function the following:
1- `state = {...initialState}` => gives an empty object
2- remove the `initialState` from the args and do the assignment inside the function. => gives undefined

any idea why?

```js
const initialState = {
  clientsArray: [],
  shouldFetchClients: false,
  isFetchingClients: false,
  fetchClientsError: null,
};

export default function clientsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CLIENTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        clientsArray: action.payload,
        isFetchingClients: false,
     };
    case FETCH_CLIENTS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        fetchClientsError: action.payload,
        isFetchingClients: false,
      };
    case FETCH_CLIENTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetchingClients: true,
        shouldFetchClients: true,
        clientsArray: null,
      };
     default:
      return state;
   }
  }
```

This is a reducer's code, and I am using combineReducers function to define the RootReducer :

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
//REDUCER FILES IMPORTS HERE

export default combineReducers({ 
clients: clientsReducer,
admins: adminsReducer 
})
```

then, in createStore I have:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import createFilter from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';

// CONNECTED-REACT-ROUTER
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { routerMiddleware, connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
export const store = createStore(
  connectRouter(history)(persistedReducer),
  composeEnhancer(
    applyMiddleware(
      routerMiddleware(history),
      sagaMiddleware,
      thunk,
      createLogService(true),
    ),
  ),
);
```